# Creating borders just at the top and bottom of some content

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to do so using CSS

```
    ---------------------
      SOME CONTENT HERE
    ---------------------
```

so what I basically want is that the border is just at the top and bottom of whatever content there is inside (most preferably a <p></p>)
Here is some code that I was using but it definitely doesn't work the way its meant to be.

```
padding: 5px 1px;
box-shadow: 0 2px 5px black,
    0 -2px 5px #800000,
    0 0 5px black,
    0 0 5px #800000;
```

What should I do for that?

Comment: Are you looking for a shadow or border above and below the element?

Comment: Ok sorry, I knew how to create borders. I'm looking for shadow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you want a border or a shadow? You're code is telling me you want a shadow, your question asks a border. 
If border:

```css
border-top: 1px solid black;
border-bottom: 1px solid black;
```

If shadow:

```css
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 6px 2px -1px #000,  0px -6px 2px -1px #000;
box-shadow: 0px 6px 2px -1px #000,  0px -6px 2px -1px #000;
```

Examples: http://jsfiddle.net/pGGXH/69/

Comment: Yeah I wanted a shadow and now I've got it from your answer.

Answer (score 2):

you can use the below code for top and bottom borders

```
  border-top:1px dashed black;
  border-bottom:1px dashed black;
```

For shadow effect go through this **[link](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-box-shadow/)**

some modifications to the code of sebass

```
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 15px -1px #000,  0 -1px 15px -1px #000;
 box-shadow: 0px 1px 15px -1px #000,  0 -1px 15px -1px #000;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want a border, then you can do it like this.

```
.div {
    border-top: 1px solid black; 
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
}​
```

Demo - http://jsfiddle.net/9VCZU/